# Using RestrictedToMinimumLevel to Override the Default Minimum Level in Serilog

Tags: serilog

I have configured Serilog to have a default MinimumLevel of Verbose.
But I want to confine the logging to SQL Server to Warning (and up).

My config (in JSON) looks like this:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer", "My.Framework.AspNet" ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithEventType" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server=yada yada yada ;MultipleActiveResultSets=True",
          "tableName": "ErrorLogs",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": false,
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "disableTriggers": true,
            "clusteredColumnstoreIndex": false,
            "primaryKeyColumnName": "Id",
            "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ],
            "removeStandardColumns": [ "Properties" ],
            "additionalColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "EventType",
                "DataType": "bigint",
                "AllowNull": true
              }
            ],
            "id": {
              "columnName": "Id",
              "nonClusteredIndex": true
            },
            "eventType": {
              "columnName": "EventType"
            },
            "message": {
              "columnName": "Message"
            },
            "messageTemplate": {
              "columnName": "MessageTemplate"
            },
            "level": {
              "columnName": "Level",
              "storeAsEnum": false
            },
            "timeStamp": {
              "columnName": "TimeStamp",
              "convertToUtc": true
            },
            "exception": {
              "columnName": "Exception"
            },
            "logEvent": {
              "columnName": "LogEvent"
            }
          }
        }        
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "App API"
    }
  }
}
```

Upon inspecting my logs, I'm seeing everything from Verbose up.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the `restrictedToMinimumLevel` property?
I also tried placing it inside the `Args` property, with no luck.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried it but upon [this](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/104) GitHub issue I think `restrictedToMinimumLevel` should be in `Args`. So change your `WriteTo` configuration like this:

```json
"WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning",
          "connectionString": "Server=yada yada yada ;MultipleActiveResultSets=True",
          "tableName": "ErrorLogs",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": false,
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "disableTriggers": true,
            "clusteredColumnstoreIndex": false,
            "primaryKeyColumnName": "Id",
            "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ],
            "removeStandardColumns": [ "Properties" ],
            "additionalColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "EventType",
                "DataType": "bigint",
                "AllowNull": true
              }
            ],
            "id": {
              "columnName": "Id",
              "nonClusteredIndex": true
            },
            "eventType": {
              "columnName": "EventType"
            },
            "message": {
              "columnName": "Message"
            },
            "messageTemplate": {
              "columnName": "MessageTemplate"
            },
            "level": {
              "columnName": "Level",
              "storeAsEnum": false
            },
            "timeStamp": {
              "columnName": "TimeStamp",
              "convertToUtc": true
            },
            "exception": {
              "columnName": "Exception"
            },
            "logEvent": {
              "columnName": "LogEvent"
            }
          }
        }        
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I had already tried that to no avail. For some reason, with the MsSqlServer sink, it is meant to go outside the args object. See https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#json-microsoftextensionsconfiguration

Comment: Yeah. Turns out my question is completely redundant. It does work when placed inside args. Not sure why my eyeballs failed me on that day. Perhaps I was looking at the wrong database.

Answer (score 4):

For the `restrictedToMinimumLevel` to work via configuration through `appSettings.json`, the `restrictedToMinimumLevel` must be inside the `Args` section [as it's described in the documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#json-microsoftextensionsconfiguration). There's nothing unique about the MsSQLServer sink that would require the configuration to be any different.

[image]

As you can see, only events with log level `>= Warning` are stored in the SQL Server table:

[image]

---

#### Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Debugging;

namespace ReproSerilogSO66019586
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", msg));

            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateLogger();

            Log.Verbose("This is Verbose!");
            Log.Debug("This is Debug!");
            Log.Information("This is Information!");
            Log.Warning("This is Warning!");
            Log.Error("This is Error!");
            Log.Fatal("This is Fatal!");

            Log.CloseAndFlush();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### appSettings.json

```
{
    "Serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
        "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Verbose"
        },
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "MSSqlServer",
                "Args": {
                    "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning",
                    "connectionString": "Server=(local);MultipleActiveResultSets=True",
                    "tableName": "ErrorLogs",
                    "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
                    "columnOptionsSection": {
                        "disableTriggers": true,
                        "clusteredColumnstoreIndex": false,
                        "primaryKeyColumnName": "Id",
                        "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ],
                        "removeStandardColumns": [ "Properties" ],
                        "additionalColumns": [
                            {
                                "ColumnName": "EventType",
                                "DataType": "bigint",
                                "AllowNull": true
                            }
                        ],
                        "id": {
                            "columnName": "Id",
                            "nonClusteredIndex": true
                        },
                        "message": {
                            "columnName": "Message"
                        },
                        "messageTemplate": {
                            "columnName": "MessageTemplate"
                        },
                        "level": {
                            "columnName": "Level",
                            "storeAsEnum": false
                        },
                        "timeStamp": {
                            "columnName": "TimeStamp",
                            "convertToUtc": true
                        },
                        "exception": {
                            "columnName": "Exception"
                        },
                        "logEvent": {
                            "columnName": "LogEvent"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "Properties": {
            "Application": "App API"
        }
    }
}
```